# ¿Como pasar un dataTable de un webform a otro?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un webform con un Gridview del cual el usuario seleccionara las filas que desee para despues con el evento onclick de un Button enviar los datos seleccionados a otro webform y mostrarlos en un gridview.
Me base en este [ejemplo](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-with-CheckBox-Get-Selected-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx), solo que ahi muestran los dos gridviews en el mismo webform y yo necesito enviar el dataTable llenado con los datos seleccionados a otro webform.
Aqui mi codigo

```html
protected void Pasardatos_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] { new DataColumn("Cod"), new DataColumn("Nombre"), new DataColumn("Precio"),
new DataColumn("Superficie")});
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);
if (chkRow.Checked)
{
string cod = row.Cells[1].Text;
string nom = row.Cells[2].Text;
string precio = row.Cells[3].Text;
string surp = row.Cells[4].Text;
dt.Rows.Add(cod, nom,precio,superficie);
}
}
}
Response.Redirect("Otro_webform.aspx?datos del dt"+...);
}
```

Aclaro que los datos que se seleccionan se pasar correctamente al datatble el problema es como enviarlos y como recibirlos.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma mas simple de pasar datos de este tipo entre `webform` es por medio del objeto `Session`

[Introduction To ASP.NET Sessions](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/225740/introduction-of-session-in-Asp-Net/)

Entonces usarias

```
Session["datos"] = dt;

Response.Redirect("Otro_webform.aspx");
```

en el form de destino tomarias los datos usando

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["datos"];
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado bien, muchas gracias